# 16.04 Function key Brightnesson ASUS X550J

Tags: 16.04, brightness, asus, function-keys

I am using ASUS X550J. All my fn functions are working fine(volume, touchpad,...) except brightness control(fn+f5/f6).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Depends on your graphics card , can you identify your graphics card please.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!"
```

Save the file, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

This will enable the Fn+F5 and F6 keys and also lid close/open events.

You may also need to redirect to `intel_backlight` in X11 settings.

It can be done by adding `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with this content:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: I bought this laptop yesterday ))